# Keras Model Accuracy differs after loading the same saved model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, model, deep-learning, keras

I trained a Keras Sequential Model and Loaded the same later. Both the model are giving different accuracy.
I have came across a similar question but was not able solve the problem.

Sample Code :
Loading and Traing the model

```
model = gensim.models.FastText.load('abc.simple') 
X,y = load_data()
Vectors = np.array(vectors(X)) 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Vectors, np.array(y), 
test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],100,max_tokens,1) 

X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],100,max_tokens,1)
data for input to our model
print(X_train.shape)
model2 = train()

score = model2.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print(score)
```

Training Accuracy is 90%. 
Saved the Model

```
# Saving Model
model_json = model2.to_json()
with open("model_architecture.json", "w") as json_file:
  json_file.write(model_json)
model2.save_weights("model_weights.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

But after I restarted the kernel and just loaded the saved model and runned it on same set of data, accuracy got reduced.

```
#load json and create model
json_file = open('model_architecture.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

#load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("model_weights.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")

# evaluate loaded model on test data
loaded_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', 
metrics=['accuracy'])

score = loaded_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print(score)
```

Accuracy got reduced to 75% on the same set of data.

How to make it consistent ?

I have tried the following but of no help :

```
from keras.backend import manual_variable_initialization
manual_variable_initialization(True)
```

Even , I saved the whole model at once( weights and architecture) but was not able to solve this issue

Comment: It seems to be a very known bug in keras. Check it out at https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4875. I also have this problem with no solution so far.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure, if your issue has been solved but for future comers.
I had exactly the same problem with saving and loading the weights. So on loading the model the accuracy and loss were changed greatly from 68% accuracy to 2 %. In my experiment, I am using Tensorflow as backend with Keras model layers Embedding, LSTM and Dense. My issue got solved by fixing the seed for keras which uses NumPy random generator and since I am using Tensorflow as backend, I also fixed the seed for it.
These are the lines I added at the top of my file where the model is also defined.

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(42)# keras seed fixing
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(42)# tensorflow seed fixing
```

I hope this helps.
For more information have a look at this- https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/

Comment: The seed seems to be the most logical answer but I tried this to no avail. Do you happen to have another solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem due to a silly mistake of mine - after loading the model I had in my data generator the shuffle option (useful for the training) turned to `True` instead of `False`. After changing it to `False` the model predicted as expected. It would be nice if keras could take care of this automatically. This is my critical code part:

```
pred_generator = pred_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory='./ims_dir',
    target_size=(100, 100),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=1,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=False,
)

model = load_model(logpath_ms)

pred=model.predict_generator(pred_generator, steps = N, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**My code worked when I scaled my dataset before reevaluating the model**. I did this treatment before saving the model and had forgotten to repeat this procedure when I opened the model and wanted to evaluate it again. After I did that, the accuracy value appeared as it should \o/

```
model_saved = keras.models.load_model('tuned_cnn_1D_HAR_example.h5')

trainX, trainy, testX, testy = load_dataset()
trainX, testX = scale_data(trainX, testX, True) 
score = model_saved.evaluate(testX, testy, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model_saved.metrics_names[1], score[1]*100))
```

inside of my function scale_data I used **StandardScaler()**